My OpenVPN does not work since installing a Wireguard VPN as well
I used to access certain databases through my OpenVPN by connecting through the OpenVPN GUI. Recently I also installed WireGuard for a different VPN. Since installing WireGuard, my connection to OpenVPN does not work anymore. I can still connect, as shown in the GUI, however I keep getting FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host ***, user ***, database ***, SSL on when connecting to my database.
I have deactivated my WireGuard connection, closed the application and even killed it through my task manager. However I still cannot connect to the database.
Is it normal for only one connection to be working, or that WireGuard blocks my OpenVPN from working in the background?

Is it normal for only one connection to be working The answer is: it depends. What are the two VPN for? Is any of them supposed / expected to make you use the VPN server as your effective Internet gateway? that WireGuard blocks my OpenVPN from working in the background What's the client OS?

The main purpose of the VPNs is to access certain databases. And my OS is Windows 11

Is it an IP address or a domain name in host ***? To be frank it doesn't sound like a problem caused by connecting to an extra VPN. Either way, you should be fine with multiple VPNs as long as their IP subnets (including destinations covered by the routes they advertise) do not conflict with each other and that they do not configure effectively a default route on the client host (but just routes for specific destinations). Also make sure you don't enable any kill-switch offered by the VPN clients.

Namely you want to avoid 0.0.0.0/0 in AllowedIPs= in the wg conf, and redirect-gateway (with or without def1) in the ovpn conf (the tricky thing with openvpn is the option could be pushed by the server, which means you'd need to check log or route table and see if you need a pull-filter).
